# Route redirect not working in Angular4.0.0-beta.1

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router

I have two routing modules imported in my main module. One routing module should contain routes everyone can access (`test-routing.module.ts`), and the other should contain routes only logged in users can access (`routing.module.ts`).

**Problem**:
I want to set `home` route as default for routes in `routing.module.ts`, but it's not working unless I set it in `test-routing.module.ts`. Can someone explain why is this so, and is it a bug? Because it worked with router version `3.1.1`

- plunker using router version `4.0.0-beta.1`: https://plnkr.co/edit/kjTI5Gg09qsq47k16oQa?p=preview
- plunker using router version `3.1.1`: https://plnkr.co/edit/7Ow2eCVc6QWI6PxfHSRs

Here's my code:

*routing.module.ts*:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                component: MainComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        redirectTo: '/home',
                        pathMatch: 'full'

                    },
                    {
                        path: 'home',
                        component: HomeComponent
                    },
                    { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
                ] 
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class MyRoutingModule { }
```

*test-routing.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                component: MainComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'test',
                        component: TestComponent
                    }
                ]
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class TestRoutingModule { }
```

*app.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, 
  TestRoutingModule,
  MyRoutingModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(
      [
        { path: '', component: MainComponent }
      ],  { useHash: false })
  ],
  declarations: [ App, MainComponent, HomeComponent, TestComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but that looks like a very weird Routing construction and it's more an unfortunate feature that it works with a previous version. I suggest you make a `HomeModule` and a `TestModule` and define the routing in there.

Comment: @PierreDuc can you explain why? I'm mostly interested in the reasoning why it doesn't (or why it shouldn't) work. I don't understand why isn't an empty path recognized at all. I tried adding a component to it to make sure it's not only about redirect and it didn't work either...